# issues with password_verify in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Doing a school assignment so this is probably a trivial question.

Users can create accounts on my "website". I store their passwords using `password_hash()`. So, at the login page I use

```
 $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

where `$password` is the password the user inputs in the form.

At this point everything works great, a hashed password is saved (I have a limit of 255 characters so there are no problems regarding the size). However, when I, in my login form, want to use `password_verify()` I have problems. A small code snippet:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = $email";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (password_verify($password, $result))
{
    echo 'Successful!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Unsuccessful!';
}
```

`$result` is in this case the hashed password from my database.

When I `var_dump($result)` I get `bool(false)`. Am i just misunderstanding the functions or am I just messing up my query?

Comment: `$result` is a resultset, not a string value..... you need to fetch the row from the resultset (using a mysqli_fetch*) function, and then access the password element in that row - http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: email is varcare filed must be in quote $sql = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE email ='". $email."'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$hash = $result['password'];

if (password_verify($password, $hash))
{
   echo 'Successful!';
}
else
{
  echo 'Unsuccessful!';
}
```

- You didn't fetch the results.
- If you put a variable in a query that is an string you must use '' quotes.

Comment: you answered too fast, apparently i need to wait four more minutes! :)

Comment: Ah well I'm happy I could help :D